# Swift 5 custom navigation bar cover title and buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After seeking a lot and trying many solutions, nope fixed my problem.
In my app I customized the UINavigationController in order to have blur effect:

`import UIKit
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let visualEffectView   = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .regular))
    visualEffectView.frame = (self.navigationBar.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -40).offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -40))
    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)
    self.navigationBar.sendSubviewToBack(visualEffectView)
}

}`

Then in Main.storyboard I selected the customized class for the navigation controller item.

The blur effect works properly, the status icons are correctly visible, but not the standard navigation bar items: left button, title and right button.

For a moment they appears but soon after the customized navigation bar covers them.

[image]

I'm using Xcode 12.4 and I'm running the app on iPhone Xr.

How can I show the navigation bar elements again?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Translucent navigation bars in iOS already blur the content behind the bar, so you shouldn't need to add a `UIVisualEffectView` nor set a `backgroundImage`.

If you modify your code to just:

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}
```

does this not achieve the visual effect you're looking for?

If not, please try the following adjustment to your methodology:

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

    // create a UIImageView
    let backgroundImage: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    backgroundImage.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    backgroundImage.image = UIImage()

    // add a blur effect to the ImageView
    let visualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .regular))
    visualEffectView.frame = (self.navigationBar.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -40).offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -40))
    backgroundImage.addSubview (visualEffectView)

    // and set that as your backgroundImage on the navigationBar
    self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage.image, for: .default)
}
```

this adds the blur effect to the backgroundImage.  This seems to work for me, but the visual effect is no different than just using my first suggestion, likely because `backgroundImage.image == nil`.

This is certainly an improved approach in that it doesn't add unexpected subviews into the `UINavigationBar` view hierarchy, and I observed both methods did not affect the visibility of the bar controls.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want to achieve. If I use your code and put .dark as blur effect, nothing happens... I want a total control on blur effect and the subviews. Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: using `backgroundImage` is probably your best shot, my example originally did not set a `UIImage` to the background `UIImageView`, I've modified the example